# Two Time Pad Attack

Tags: cryptography, cracking

Currently im doing online challenges in cryptography. One challenge is to crack a "One Time Pad". I'd like to kindly ask you guys for a hint. Im stuck with this now for a while.

The cipher text looks like this:

```
4de61dd9dab5e0701f5e664ff522de12bd588051da4d3f62df
3c3303e696139af0280308f5720d5e45efaa03bc6d37d84294
06b25cded0e2fb74045f681bd4378a5bba10901fd6513b2cc0
343c0aa3c6138df02d1f46e63a090d07f3b602bc653bcd5ad1
00fa5890c4f0e062175d2348bd30c25dbb44c951c0503f6fd8
3d3114b28e1390b4611146e53a091c45f8bc01f56f2ac1459f
07be1dc2ccf8fc67131a3355f326c957ba438403cc03362adf
213b14b5ca5290b537155aa1680d0b54eff916bc7e3fcc06d1
15fc5990c1f4e574565b665cf22cce12ac5e8a04d24b7a3dca
3b3a09abc60191a533134da17c070c07eeb803fd207efc4294
54f552dccdb5fd64115d234fbd2ad912eb7d841fc142372adc
3c324684871599b92f0340ee68065c09
```

(Each line of the cipher has 50 chars btw)
I know that the pad is 50 chars long. So is has been used for about 11.7 times.
I also have done a lot of researches online so I know

M = Message | P = Pad | C = Cipher

- M1 = C1 XOR P1
- C1 XOR C2 = M1 XOR M2

So I XORed the first line with the second line (I assume it's additionaly converted as HEX). The result is the following:

```
71d51e3f4ca67a80375d6eba872f805752f283edb77ae7204b
```

After this I converted it to ASCII and received this:

```
qÕ?L¦z7]nº/WRòí·zç K
```

So here I knew something is wrong,nevertheless I tried to decrypt the first line with my result and hoped I get a result.
But surprise, the result  is

```
VæÙÚµàp^rOõ"Þ½XQÚM?bß
```

What have I done wrong? What would be a possible method to solve this challenge? Nothing on the internet really helped me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6020/many-time-pad-attack

Comment: See coursera.org: Cryptography, Week 2, "Limitations of the One-Time Pad. tldr; It is not that simple.

Comment: The second byte starts with a high bit set, this could mean something is not right. I don't think these are separate cipher texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at hexadecimal characters. Two hex characters are a single byte. A single byte is one ASCII character. It seems to me that you have to take line 1 & 2 together (etc.). The values in the bytes seem to show this as well. In other words, the cipher has been used about 5.8 times.

```
4de61dd9dab5e0701f5e664ff522de12bd588051da4d3f62df3c3303e696139af0280308f5720d5e45efaa03bc6d37d84294
06b25cded0e2fb74045f681bd4378a5bba10901fd6513b2cc0343c0aa3c6138df02d1f46e63a090d07f3b602bc653bcd5ad1
00fa5890c4f0e062175d2348bd30c25dbb44c951c0503f6fd83d3114b28e1390b4611146e53a091c45f8bc01f56f2ac1459f
07be1dc2ccf8fc67131a3355f326c957ba438403cc03362adf213b14b5ca5290b537155aa1680d0b54eff916bc7e3fcc06d1
15fc5990c1f4e574565b665cf22cce12ac5e8a04d24b7a3dca3b3a09abc60191a533134da17c070c07eeb803fd207efc4294
54f552dccdb5fd64115d234fbd2ad912eb7d841fc142372adc3c324684871599b92f0340ee68065c09
```

Note that the result of XOR-ing the values will not result in ASCII; it will result in M1 XOR M2. Now if both are e.g. digits then `'1' XOR '2'` will translate into `31 XOR 32` (hex) or `00110001 XOR 00110010` (bin) which will result in `00000011` (bin), `03` (hex) or the non-printable control character `End-of-Text` in ASCII.

Comment: So first octete in second line next to first octete in first line ect.?

Comment: Showed what I meant. Note that you have to group the hex digits two by two. Note that each high valued byte (e.g. `e6`, the second octet on the first line) now corresponds to a high valued byte (`b2`, the second octet on the second line). This is what you should expect because the first bit of each byte MUST XOR to 0 for ASCII. ASCII is a 7 bit encoding where the high bit is always 0, and 0 XOR 0 (bin) is of course also 0.

Comment: After XORing 2 lines I understand what you mean xD
So if I have (M1 XOR M2) I need to "crib dragging" right?

Comment: I must say that the resulting text is absolute BS, I don't know which teacher wrote that up, but he/she should get a good spankin'. Be warned: *the first character is incorrect*, and the text contains uppercase, lowercase, symbols and spaces. Your ciphertext should start with `3d`, not `4d` (typo from your side?). Furthermore, the words are split and continue on the next line.

Comment: Which tool do you use for crib dragging?

Comment: @ManuelBürge Eh, I programmed a new one... Already created one for the Crypto I course of Boneh. Had to use some tricks such as importing some letter frequencies and making up some frequencies for things like spaces and other frequent symbols.